# No HTTP response detected google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using content.ad to show ads in my site and content.ad GA code is throwing error in tag manager. 
i dont have any control over there code as it is being inserted through javascript.

Here is screenshot of error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/btZRc.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgA5e.jpg

here is my site 
http://way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/photos-slideshow.php/925184/the
my site GA code is fine and not giving any error. its Content.ad network ads creating problem.how can i solve that.

Comment: a million ads show up on your site - so what's the problem, you haven't shown any code you need help with, so not sure how SO can help

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your reply. my GA code is copy paste from google analytics and i have shared link and i think it can give any clue.ihave not shared code as i am not aware what to share . :(

Comment: you state that the GA code doesn't produce any errors in the web page - so how is viewing your web page (which you linked to) going allow anyone to help you with the issue as the issue certainly isn't on your web page which you clearly stated

Comment: have you searched SO for "google analytics no http response detected" ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365579/google-analytics-no-http-response-detected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566288/google-analytics-ecommerce-tracking-no-http-response-detected or the internet https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/411360-google-analytics-no-http-response-detected/ ... or direct from the source - https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/3059154#http_response

Comment: @JaromandaX yes .searched 10-15 articles but none is relivant.content.ad is not in my control so came here

Comment: none of those links suggest you need to have control of content.ad - they discuss a similar problem to yours - I take it you've done what google suggest, and you don't use both Google TA extension and Ad Block Plus extension on Chrome?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes i checked ad block i dont have ad block installed

Comment: OK, well, as SO is about code issues, and you have no code issues (because you've followed [this advice](https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/3059154#http_response) ) then it's pretty much off topic